# Why isn't this anonymous function returning?

Tags: javascript

I know this is complete purposeless code I'm just experimenting with anonymous functions with code I have already written and had at hand. I can't figure out though why it array isn't returning?

```
(function() {
    function Employee(name, age, pay) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.pay = pay || 800;
    }

    function Manager(name, age, pay) {
        Employee.call(this, name, age, pay);
        this.reports = [];
    }
    Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
    Manager.prototype.addReport = function(report) {
        this.reports.push(report);
    }

    function Cashier(name, age, pay) {
        Employee.call(this, name, age, pay);
    }
    Cashier.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
    var ary = [Cashier, Manager];
    return ary;
}());
```

Comment: When asking for help, taking the time to format the code consistently and readably will help you get answers. *(I've done it for you this time.)*

Comment: The array _is_ returning.

Comment: Fully agree with @T.J.Crowder. Now, _Anonymous_ functions cannot be invoked, right? So, where exactly are you checking if they return something or not. Besides, I wonder about the need of using anonymous functions. For me, code-reviewing is far easier when there is a standard way of defining functions. The equivalent would be defining a named function and invoking it just after it had been defined. isn't it clearer?

Comment: @FDavidov: *"Now, Anonymous functions cannot be invoked, right?"* Sure they can, and the anonymous function in the question *is* being invoked.

Comment: Yes, I know, self-invocation as in the example. My point is more about SW Engineering guidelines (specially, maintainability, a concept forgotten long time ago by many...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...why it array isn't returning?

It is. You're just not doing anything with that return value; see `***` comment on first line:

```js
var result = (function() { // ****
    function Employee(name, age, pay) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.pay = pay || 800;
    }

    function Manager(name, age, pay) {
        Employee.call(this, name, age, pay);
        this.reports = [];
    }
    Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
    Manager.prototype.addReport = function(report) {
        this.reports.push(report);
    }

    function Cashier(name, age, pay) {
        Employee.call(this, name, age, pay);
    }
    Cashier.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
    var ary = [Cashier, Manager];
    return ary;
}());
console.log(result);
```

Comment: ok, I was under the impression wen you return an object from function in its accessible from the scope it was returned into so I was thinking I access the ary object from the console like a global by typing in 'ary'. I'm assuming I'm wrong on that then?

Comment: @Brandon: Yes, `ary` (the variable) is only accessible to code within the anonymous function. That's the *purpose* of the anonymous function above: To keep the things inside it private except for the ones you choose to make accessible by returning them. The array it refers to is accessible, but only if you make use of the value the anonymous function returns.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this code is returning two constructor function objects. Try running it on your console :-

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding snapshot, you could have just copied OP code in a stack snippet.

Comment: yeah sorry I saw the object I should have said that, thats one of the reasons why I'm confused. When I type obj into the console it says obj is 'undefined'?